# Json framework does not work on iOS 4

Tags: iphone

is anybody able to use JSON framework on iPhone sdk 4,it is working fine on sdk 3.1.2 but not on iPhone sdk 4.

Comment: You'll have to specify *which* JSON framework you're talking about, there are a few.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm successfully able to use this framework on iOS4:

https://github.com/stig/json-framework/

Comment: Thanks Avalanchis, i am using the same framework,and if it is working for you it should for me also, think there is something else that is at fault,i'll debug it again.

Comment: I did copy the JSON folder into my project, as opposed to trying to link to it outside of my project if that helps.

Comment: Thanks Avalanchis was able to build the project by copying the project and libjson.a into my project or else libjson.a gives error if we use the JSON framework as additional SDK,don't know why though.